# How do you fix a wooden fence board that’s bowing?

Tags: wood, fence, board

I’ve tried looking for some videos online and couldn’t find anything. Maybe I just don’t the correct terminology to use. How would one go about repairing a fence board like this, where’s its bowing at the bottom?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Generally, replacing the picket is easiest.

You could also get a pressure treated 2x4 and run it along the bottom and screw it down to adjacent pickets and gently screwing the bowed one to the 2x4. But, you likely need to do that slowly to prevent cracking the board.

Comment: +1.  Those pickets are like $2 each.  The new one is going to stand out at first but after like a year it will blend right in.

Comment: Yeah. That picket has some juvenile wood, reaction wood, or something with a different swelling response to moisture. Or maybe way back it was installed green and dehydrated so disproportionately on one side before the other that it is now permanently deformed.

Comment: When I've tried to pull a warped board like that back into place, the screw would usually pull right through the board.